# Part of Plane not rendering

Tags: rendering

Am using Blender 2.82A    I have done this before... using same material... I've gone through everything and even deleted the plane and added a new one.. same issue
I put a lake material on the plane... can see the material on it in Material Preview but when it's in render mode, much of the lake material not showing...  I've moved the lighting around, different direction and it doesn't change anything...  eventually, I want only the lake material at the right side of the plane...  but got it on all of the plane right now trying to figure out why it is not showing up...  I have done a few other scenes using the lake and not had any issue.. did the same thing in this one but for some reason not showing up all of it...
Any idea as to what I might look at and see why this is not showing up...  Doesn't matter where the sun is, it is not showing up properly on this scene...  I have even tried a plane as an Emission above the scene and same issue...
thanks   I tried to put a picture of what it looks like and it would not post with the image

Comment: Any chance you could post a screenshot of what you're (not) seeing?

Comment: Can you post it on imgur ot something, and provide a link? I can put it in your question for you if I can see the image. I think I know what's happening, but I can't tell from the description alone.

Comment: Ok, well without an image, here's my best guess - you have your camera's far clip distance too low. Click on your camera in the scene tree, then down under the camera properties tab, change the "end" value to something higher and see if it changes anything.